# Stored procedure part optimization

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@xml XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
    declare @idoc INT; -- table(CentreId bigint, LanguageId int)
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml

--declare @LangCentre table (CentreId bigint, LanguageId int) 
CREATE TABLE #LangCentre
(
   CentreId bigint, 
   LanguageId INT
)

INSERT into #LangCentre (CentreId, LanguageId)(
SELECT * from OPENXML (@idoc, '/T/R', 2) WITH (CentreId BIGINT 'C', LanguageId int 'L'))

CREATE TABLE #LangCentreCTranslation
(
   CentreId BIGINT, 
   LanguageId INT,
   CentreTranslationId BIGINT
)    

INSERT into #LangCentreCTranslation (CentreId, LanguageId, CentreTranslationId)(
    SELECT 
    lc.CentreId,
    lc.LanguageId,      
    CASE WHEN ct.id IS NULL THEN ct2.id ELSE ct.id END AS CentreTranslationId 
    FROM #LangCentre lc
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreTranslation ct ON ct.centre_id = lc.CentreId AND ct.language_id = lc.LanguageId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreTranslation ct2 ON ct2.centre_id = lc.CentreId and ct2.language_id = 1
)

SELECT  
lcct.CentreTranslationId,       
lcct.LanguageId,
lcct.CentreId AS CentreID ,
ptBusinessCentre.about AS BusinessCentreDescription,
ptBusinessCentre.meta_title AS BusinessCentreMetaTitle,
ptBusinessCentre.meta_keywords AS BusinessCentreMetaKeywords,
ptBusinessCentre.meta_description AS BusinessCentreMetaDescription,

ptOffice.about AS OfficeDescription,
ptOffice.meta_title AS OfficeMetaTitle,
ptOffice.meta_keywords AS OfficeMetaKeywords,
ptOffice.meta_description AS OfficeMetaDescription,

ptVirtualOffice.about AS VirtualOfficeDescription,
ptVirtualOffice.meta_title AS VirtualOfficeMetaTitle,
ptVirtualOffice.meta_keywords AS VirtualOfficeMetaKeywords,
ptVirtualOffice.meta_description AS VirtualOfficeMetaDescription,

ptMeetingRoom.about AS MeetingRoomDescription,
ptMeetingRoom.meta_title AS MeetingRoomMetaTitle,
ptMeetingRoom.meta_keywords AS MeetingRoomMetaKeywords,
ptMeetingRoom.meta_description AS MeetingRoomMetaDescription,

ptBusinessLounge.about AS BusinessLoungeDescription,
ptBusinessLounge.meta_title AS BusinessLoungeMetaTitle,
ptBusinessLounge.meta_keywords AS BusinessLoungeMetaKeywords,
ptBusinessLounge.meta_description AS BusinessLoungeMetaDescription,

ptDayOffice.about AS DayOfficeDescription,
ptDayOffice.meta_title AS DayOfficeMetaTitle,
ptDayOffice.meta_keywords AS DayOfficeMetaKeywords,
ptDayOffice.meta_description AS DayOfficeMetaDescription,

ptVideoConferencing.about AS VideoConferencingDescription,
ptVideoConferencing.meta_title AS VideoConferencingMetaTitle,
ptVideoConferencing.meta_keywords AS VideoConferencingMetaKeywords,
ptVideoConferencing.meta_description AS VideoConferencingMetaDescription,

ptManagedOfficeSolutions.about AS ManagedOfficeSolutionsDescription,    
ptManagedOfficeSolutions.meta_title AS ManagedOfficeSolutionsMetaTitle, 
ptManagedOfficeSolutions.meta_keywords AS ManagedOfficeSolutionsMetaKeywords,   
ptManagedOfficeSolutions.meta_description AS ManagedOfficeSolutionsMetaDescription, 

ptTelecommunications.about AS TelecommunicationsDescription,    
ptTelecommunications.meta_title AS TelecommunicationsMetaTitle, 
ptTelecommunications.meta_keywords AS TelecommunicationsMetaKeywords,   
ptTelecommunications.meta_description AS TelecommunicationsMetaDescription, 

--

ctContact.manager AS CentreManager,
ctContact.area_director AS AreaDirector,
ctContact.rmm AS RMM,
ctContact.operations_director AS OperationsDirector,
ctContact.financial_controller AS FinancialController,
ctContact.sales_fax_line AS SalesFaxLine,
ctContact.agents_hotline AS AgentsHotline,
ctContact.emergency_phone AS EmergencyPhone,
ctContact.emergency_pager AS EmergencyPager,
ctContact.receptionist_phone AS ReceptionistPhone,
ctContact.rsc_speed_dials AS RscSpeedDials,
ctContact.toll_free AS TollFree,
ctContact.voicemail_server AS VoicemailServer,
ctContact.additional_phone AS AdditionalPhone,
ctContact.additional_fax AS AdditionalFax,

ctContact.centre_manager_email as CentreManagerEmail,
ctContact.area_director_address as AreaDirectorEmail,

ctRooms.number_of_offices AS NumberOfOffices,
ctRooms.number_of_meeting_rooms AS NumberOfMeetingRooms,
ctRooms.number_of_training_rooms AS NumberOfTrainingRooms,
ctRooms.number_of_conference_rooms AS NumberOfConferenceRooms,
ctRooms.number_of_workstations AS NumberOfWorkstations,
ctRooms.number_of_floors AS NumberOfFloors,
ctRooms.number_of_parking_spaces AS NumberOfParkingSpaces,
ctRooms.parking_costs AS ParkingCosts,
ctRooms.floor_area AS FloorArea,
ctRooms.floorplan AS Floorplan,

ctOpeningHours.monday_opening AS MondayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.monday_closing AS MondayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.tuesday_opening AS TuesdayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.tuesday_closing AS TuesdayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.wednesday_opening AS WednesdayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.wednesday_closing AS WednesdayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.thursday_opening AS ThursdayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.thursday_closing AS ThursdayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.friday_opening AS FridayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.friday_closing AS FridayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.saturday_opening AS SaturdayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.saturday_closing AS SaturdayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.sunday_opening AS SundayOpening,
ctOpeningHours.sunday_closing AS SundayClosing,
ctOpeningHours.timezone_id AS TimezoneId,

ctLounge.opening_times_text AS OpeningTimesText,
ctLounge.number_of_armchairs AS NumberOfArmchairs,
ctLounge.number_of_seats_in_library as NumberOfSeatsInLibrary,
ctLounge.number_of_bar_stools as NumberOfBarStools,
ctLounge.number_of_other_seats as NumberOfOtherSeats,
ctLounge.number_of_thinkpods AS NumberOfThinkpods,
ctLounge.number_of_mac_pc_bars AS NumberOfMacPcBars,
ctLounge.number_of_flatscreen_tvs AS NumberOfFlatScreenTvs,
ctLounge.number_of_newspapers AS NumberOfNewspapers,

--
ctLounge.lounge_type as LoungeType,
ctLounge.alternative_to_businesslounge as AlternativeToBL,
ctLounge.last_refubrishment_date as LastRefurbishmentDate,
ctLounge.lounge_location_in_centre as LocationInCentre,
ctLounge.lounge_visible_from_outside as VisibleFromOutside,
ctLounge.signage_to_advertise as SignageOutsideToAdvertise,
ctLounge.reason_for_no_advertisment as ReasonForNoAdvertisement,
ctLounge.type_of_access_control as TypeOfAccessControl,
ctLounge.monday_opening as LoungeMondayOpening,
ctLounge.monday_closing as LoungeMondayClosing,
ctLounge.tuesday_opening as LoungeTuesdayOpening,
ctLounge.tuesday_closing as LoungeTuesdayClosing,
ctLounge.wednesday_opening as LoungeWednesdayOpening,
ctLounge.wednesday_closing as LoungeWednesdayClosing,
ctLounge.thursday_opening as LoungeThursdayOpening,
ctLounge.thursday_closing as LoungeThursdayClosing,
ctLounge.friday_opening as LoungeFridayOpening,
ctLounge.friday_closing as LoungeFridayClosing,
ctLounge.saturday_opening as LoungeSaturdayOpening,
ctLounge.saturday_closing as LoungeSaturdayClosing,
ctLounge.sunday_opening as LoungeSundayOpening,
ctLounge.sunday_closing as LoungeSundayClosing,
ctLounge.type_of_location as TypeOfLocation,
ctLounge.parking_facilities as ParkingFacilities,
ctLounge.have_to_pass_through_security as HaveToPassThroughSecurity,
ctLounge.is_advanced_security_notification_requiered as IsAdvancedSecurityNotificationRequiered,
ctLounge.business_lounge_floor as BusinessLoungeFloor,
ctLounge.type_of_room as TypeOfRoom,
ctLounge.suitable_for_disabled as SuitableForDisabled,
ctLounge.does_directly_receive_light as DoesDirectlyReceiveLight,
ctLounge.airconditioning as Airconditioning,
ctLounge.is_wifi_available as IsWifiAvailable,
ctLounge.is_ethernet_available as IsEthernetAvailable,
ctLounge.number_of_computers as NumberOfComputers,
ctLounge.other_internet_access as OtherInternetAccess,
ctLounge.are_beverages_available as AreBeveragesAvailable,
ctLounge.type_of_coffee_available as TypeOfCoffeeAvailable,
ctLounge.copy_fax_print_facilities as CopyFaxPrintFacilities,
ctLounge.business_support as BusinessSupport,
ctLounge.mobile_charging_points as MobileChargingPoints,
ctLounge.newspapers_and_magazines as NewspapersAndMagazines,
ctLounge.bathroom_facilities_available as BathroomFacilitiesAvailable,
ctLounge.showers_available as ShowersAvailable,
(case 
when ctLounge.grade=1 then 'Grade A'
when ctLounge.grade=2 then 'Grade B'
when ctLounge.grade=3 then 'Grade C'
when ctLounge.grade=4 then 'Ungraded'
else 'No Value' end) as Grade,

--

ctOtherInfo.bank_name AS BankName,
ctOtherInfo.bank_address AS BankAddress,
ctOtherInfo.bank_account_number AS BankAccountNumber,
ctOtherInfo.bank_sort_code AS BankSortCode,
ctOtherInfo.bank_swift_code AS BankSwiftCode,
ctOtherInfo.vc_equipment AS VcEquipment,
ctOtherInfo.vc_equipment_working AS VcEquipmentWorking,
ctOtherInfo.isdn AS ISDN,
ctOtherInfo.vc_contact AS VcContact,
ctOtherInfo.vc_phone AS VcPhone,
ctOtherInfo.equipment_make AS EquipmentMake,
ctOtherInfo.speed AS Speed,
ctOtherInfo.additional_charges AS AdditionalCharges,
ctOtherInfo.room_capacity AS RoomCapacity,
ctOtherInfo.out_of_hours_vc_contact AS OutOfHoursVcContact,
ctOtherInfo.vc_room_names AS VcRoomNames,
ctOtherInfo.maximum_bandwidth AS MaximumBandwidth,
ctOtherInfo.floodgate_installed AS FloodgateInstalled,
ctOtherInfo.encryption AS Encryption,
ctOtherInfo.underfloor_cat5_cabling AS UnderfloorCat5Cabling,
ctOtherInfo.lockable_comms_rack_space AS LockableCommsRackSpace,

isNULL(ct.name, cn.name) as CentreName,
ct.name as TranslatedName,
ct.address_line_1 as Address1,
ct.address_line_2 as Address2,
ct.address_line_3 as Address3,
ct.city as Town,
ct.postcode as PostalCode,
ct.country as Country,
ct.county as State,


cn.number as Number,
cn.url as Url,
cn.virtual_tour_url as VirtualTourUrl,
(CASE WHEN status.cnt>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ShowCentre,
cnInactivityReason.[description] as ReasonForNotShowing,
cn.alternate_name as AlternateName,
cn.date_opened as OpeningDate,
cn.closed as Closed,
cn.date_closed as DateClosed,
cn.phone as Phone,
cn.fax as Fax,
cn.email as Email,
cn.position.Lat as Latitude,
cn.position.Long as Longtitude,
images.cnt as ImagesCount,
cn.area as Area,
cn.sales_cluster as SalesCluster,
cn.is_additionl_security_check_required as AdditionalSecurityCheck,
ct.country as TranslatedCountry,
cn.virtual_tour as VirtualTour,
ct.about as OriginalDescription,
ct.directions as directions,
cn.centre_profile_id as CentreProfileId,
ct.amenities as AmenitiesFreeText,

STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), feature_id) FROM dbo.CentreFeature cf LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY feature_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FeatureIds,

STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), brand_id) FROM dbo.CentreBrand cf LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY brand_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as BrandIds

FROM #LangCentreCTranslation lcct
INNER JOIN dbo.Centre cn on lcct.CentreId = cn.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreTranslation ct ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ct.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptBusinessCentre ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptBusinessCentre.centre_translation_id AND ptBusinessCentre.product_id = 1
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptOffice ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptOffice.centre_translation_id AND ptOffice.product_id = 2
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptVirtualOffice ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptVirtualOffice.centre_translation_id AND ptVirtualOffice.product_id = 3
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptMeetingRoom ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptMeetingRoom.centre_translation_id AND ptMeetingRoom.product_id = 4
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptBusinessLounge ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptBusinessLounge.centre_translation_id AND ptBusinessLounge.product_id = 5
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptDayOffice ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptDayOffice.centre_translation_id AND ptDayOffice.product_id = 6
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptVideoConferencing ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptVideoConferencing.centre_translation_id AND ptVideoConferencing.product_id = 11
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptTelecommunications ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptTelecommunications.centre_translation_id AND ptTelecommunications.product_id = 12
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTranslation ptManagedOfficeSolutions ON lcct.CentreTranslationId = ptManagedOfficeSolutions.centre_translation_id AND ptManagedOfficeSolutions.product_id = 14

LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreContact ctContact ON lcct.CentreId = ctContact.centre_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreRooms ctRooms ON lcct.CentreId = ctRooms.centre_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreOpeningHours ctOpeningHours ON lcct.CentreId = ctOpeningHours.centre_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreLounge ctLounge ON lcct.CentreId = ctLounge.centre_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreOtherInfo ctOtherInfo ON lcct.CentreId = ctOtherInfo.centre_id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT centre_id, COUNT (*) as cnt from dbo.CentreStatus GROUP BY centre_id) status ON status.centre_id=lcct.CentreId
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreInactivityReason cnInactivityReason ON cn.inactivity_reason = cnInactivityReason.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT centre_id, COUNT (*) as cnt from dbo.Image2Centre GROUP BY centre_id) images ON images.centre_id=lcct.CentreId

ORDER BY isNULL(ct.name, cn.name)

DROP TABLE #LangCentreCTranslation
DROP TABLE #LangCentre

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
-- Insert statements for procedure here


END
```

The SP processes approximately 2700 records. The problem in this SP is that if I don't disable

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), feature_id) FROM dbo.CentreFeature cf LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY feature_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FeatureIds,

STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), brand_id) FROM dbo.CentreBrand cf LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY brand_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as BrandIds
```

this SP will execute in ~13 minutes, but with the above lines commented\removed it will execute in ~30s, how can I optimize these particular parts of SP to increase their performance. I can provide tables structure\execution plan if needed (don't know how to attach files though). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong:  Are columns FeatureIds and BrandIds not the same in every row of the result?

Comment: they are linked to one table (Features, Brands) but for each centre they may be different (centre 1 features: 1, 2, 3, 5; centre 2 features: 1, 3, 5, 7...)

Comment: It seems to me the expression "STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), cf.FeatureId) FROM #CnFeatures cf ORDER BY cf.FeatureId FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, )"  produces a comma separated list of all the FeatureId's in #CnFeatures, unrelated to anything else in the query.   Am I wrong?

Comment: it might be broken, as I was desperately trying to optimize it and messed up, the first working version was       `STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), feature_id) FROM dbo.CentreFeature cf LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY feature_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FeatureIds`       and `STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), brand_id) FROM dbo.CentreBrand cf LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY brand_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as BrandIds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the following 2 lines, you will notice that they are independent of the parent query.

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), feature_id) 
FROM dbo.CentreFeature cf 
LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct
ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY feature_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FeatureIds,
```

and

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), brand_id) 
FROM dbo.CentreBrand cf 
LEFT JOIN #LangCentreCTranslation lcct 
ON cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY brand_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as BrandIds
```

These queries do no not refer any column from the parent query. If this is what you want, you can create two variables and assign values from these queries and use the variables in the final `SELECT`.

I assume you are trying to accomplish something like this.

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), feature_id) 
FROM dbo.CentreFeature cf 
WHERE cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY feature_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FeatureIds,
```

and

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), brand_id) 
FROM dbo.CentreBrand cf 
WHERE cf.Centre_Id = lcct.Centreid ORDER BY brand_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as BrandIds
```

Notice that I have removed the `JOIN` and added a `WHERE` clause to refer the value of `lcct.Centreid` from the parent query and made this sub-query a co-related sub-query.

You can also optionally do this when you insert data into`#LangCentreCTranslation`

```
INSERT into #LangCentreCTranslation (CentreId, LanguageId, CentreTranslationId,BrandIds,FeatureIds)(
SELECT 
    lc.CentreId,
    lc.LanguageId,      
    CASE WHEN ct.id IS NULL THEN ct2.id ELSE ct.id END AS CentreTranslationId,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), brand_id) FROM dbo.CentreBrand cf WHERE cf.Centre_Id = lc.Centreid ORDER BY brand_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as BrandIds,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), feature_id) FROM dbo.CentreFeature cf WHERE cf.Centre_Id = lc.Centreid ORDER BY feature_id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FeatureIds
FROM #LangCentre lc
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreTranslation ct ON ct.centre_id = lc.CentreId AND ct.language_id = lc.LanguageId
LEFT JOIN dbo.CentreTranslation ct2 ON ct2.centre_id = lc.CentreId and ct2.language_id = 1
```

)

Comment: this is great, the performance is now appr. 33 seconds for 2700 rows, thank you VERY MUCH